# Return this dataset as an array of user schema objects in mongoDB

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am using MongoDB Aggregation $lookup to query two different schema collections.

What I want to do is return all the users that have been added to each artist collection.

Here is the Artist Schema

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59f7a13163241a5c8a580832"),
"artistID" : "34657839393",
"artistName" : "Mc squared",
"userID" : ObjectId("599f14855e9fcf95d0fe11a7"),
"__v" : 0
```

}

```
Artist.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { artistID }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "userID",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "UsersWithMatchedArtist"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            UsersWithMatchedArtist: 1
        }
    }
}
])
```

This returns a the following data structure.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "59f8f40686f2fa623d815256",
    "UsersWithMatchedArtist": [{Users Schema}]
  },
  {
    "_id": "59f8f40686f2f12345678901",
    "UsersWithMatchedArtist": [{Users Schema}}]
  }
]
```

I wish to have the data returned in the following structure

```
[
  {Users Schema},
  {Users Schema}
]
```

Any Suggestions on how to do this? Suggestions would be much appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I got the dataset that I was after using this query below:

```
Artist.aggregate([
     {
            $match: { artistID }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "users",
                localField: "userID",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "UsersWithMatchedArtist"
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                user: {
                    $arrayElemAt: ["$UsersWithMatchedArtist", 0]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $replaceRoot: {
                newRoot: "$user"
            }
        }
  ])
```

This returns the dataset

```
[
  {Users Schema},
  {Users Schema}
]
```